# Understanding the proof of the Springer correspondence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, geometric-representation-theory, perverse-sheaves, springer-fibres

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over an algebraically closed field $k$ with Weyl group $W$.
Let
$$
\mathcal{S} = R\pi_*\mathbb{Q}_\ell[\dim \mathcal{N}] 
$$
be the Springer sheaf, where $\mathcal{N}\subset \mathrm{Lie} (G)$ is the nilpotent cone and $\pi:\widetilde{\mathcal{N}} \rightarrow\mathcal{N}$ is the Springer resolution.

---

In Zhiwei Yun's [lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01451), the proof of the Springer correspondence contains the following passage:

> We decompose the perverse sheaf $\mathcal{S}$ into isotypical components under the $W$-action
> $$
> \mathcal{S} = \bigoplus_{\chi\in \mathrm{Irr}(W)} V_\chi\otimes S_\chi
> $$
> where $V_\chi$ is the space where $W$ acts by the irreducible representation $\chi$, and $\mathcal{S}_{\chi} = \hom_W(V_\chi, \mathcal{S})$ is a perverse sheaf on $\mathcal{N}$.
> **Since $\mathrm{End}(\mathcal{S})\cong\mathbb{Q}_\ell[W]$, we conclude that each $\mathcal{S}_\chi$ is nonzero and that**
> $$
> \hom(\mathcal{S}_\chi,\mathcal{S}_{\chi'}) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \mathbb{Q}_\ell & \chi = \chi' \\
> 0 & \mathrm{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}
> $$

I am not sure how to obtain the bolded conclusion.

I believe it should be possible to compute $\mathrm{End}(\mathcal{S})$ in terms of the multiplicity sheaves $\mathcal{S}_\chi$.
At this point in the proof, it is not yet known that the $\mathcal{S}_\chi$ are semisimple, so I do not know how to proceed in this direction.

In fact, I think the corresponding statement for complex representations is false.
I.e., if $R$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-representation of $W$ with $\mathrm{End}(R) = \mathbb{C}[W]$, then the multiplicity of each $W$-irrep in $R$ is precisely 1.
But $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C}[W]) \cong \mathbb{C}[W]$ and $\mathbb{C}[W]$ contains irreps with larger multiplicities.

---

[Crossposted from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671059/understanding-the-proof-of-the-springer-correspondence)

Comment: Hi Zyogomatic. Your bolded statement has nothing to do with perverse sheaves etc. It is simply the statement that if you have any object $M$ in a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear abelian (or even additive Karoubian complete) category, then if $End(M) = \mathbb{Q}[W]$ then $M$ breaks up in the same way the regular representation of $W$ does. This is worth thinking through carefully: all the idempotents we know from rep theory of $W$ allow us to split up our object $M$ into pieces, and we can conclude that each piece has endomorphism ring $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: (Note that your last paragraph is wrong: we have $R \cong \bigoplus V \otimes V^*$ (sum over irreps), and so each irrep $V$ occurs $\dim V^* = \dim V$ times in the regular representation. Think about your favour example, e.g. $W = S_3$.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. One thing I still do not understand is how the endomorphism ring can be just Q if the multiplicity is larger than one. This is what I was trying to say with the last paragraph.

Comment: As I said, I'd recommend thinking about $W = S_3$. In this case the regular representation $\mathbb{C}[W]$ breaks up as $\mathbb{C} \oplus \epsilon \oplus V \oplus V$ where $V$ is the 2-dimensional "natural" representation of $S_3$, and $\mathbb{C}$ and $\epsilon$ are the (one-dimensional) trivial and sign representations. (This is better suited to MSE, but I'm answering here because you don't seem to have gotten an answer there.)

Comment: Apologies if this question is really silly, but this example only makes me more confused, because I know $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}[S_3]}(V \oplus V) = \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}[S_3]}(V\otimes V^\ast) = \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(V^\ast) = M_2(\mathbb C)$. But if this argument is formal, then I think $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb {C}[S_3]) = \mathbb{C}[S_3]$ and $\mathbb{C}[S_3] = \bigoplus_{\lambda\in \mathrm{Irr}(S_3)} V_{\lambda} \otimes V^\ast_{\lambda}$ should imply $\mathrm{End}(V^\ast_{\lambda}) = \mathbb{C}$...

Comment: I would suggest reposting the rep theory question on MSE.